# cURL POST запрос отправляется, но возврахается в странном виде

Tags: php, json, post, curl

Всем доброго времени суток.
При подключении партнерской программы на сайт, столкнулся с проблемой. POST запрос через cURL отправить получается. Ответ приходит, но в искаженном виде.

```
 $array = array(
'pos'=>T_CONECT,
  'enter_point'=>T_CLIENT,
  'cash_iden'=>T_EQUIPMENT,
  'direction'=>'getbalance',
  // 'number'=> '9910000000042'
    'phone'=> '9826659615'
);      
$ch = curl_init('https://dominat.pro/poscloud/posmain/posmain_1.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $array); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);    
  
$res = json_decode($html);
```

Вот как должен выглядеть ответ:
{"error":0, "description":"Ошибок нет", "number":"9910000000042", "alive":1, "balance":1100.00}
Обычный json массив, который можно декодировать.

Вот что приходит в ответе:
{"error":0, "description":"������ ���", "number":"9910000000042", "alive":1, "balance":1100.00}
Казалось бы, одно и то же, но использование json_decode ни к чему не приводит.

Comment: ну так правильно и приходит, просто ты что-то с кодировками намутил

Comment: `if(!$res) die( json_last_error_msg() )`

Answer (score 0):

Прошу прощения. Данные приходили не в UTF-8.
Русский текст все равно приходит в виде вопросов, но теперь с массивом теперь можно работать.

```
$res = utf8_decode($html);
$res1 = json_decode($res);
```

Уверен, можно это сделать в самом запросе, но я способ пока не нашел.
Большое спасибо, teran и Jean-Claude.